# How to get first and last sequence of times in array

Tags: php

I have an array of different times throughout the day, they go up in 15 minute intervals.

```
Array
(
[0] => 12:00am
[1] => 12:15am
[2] => 12:30am
[3] => 12:45am
[4] => 1:00am
[5] => 1:15am
[6] => 1:30am
[7] => 1:45am
[8] => 2:00am
[9] => 3:15am
[10] => 3:30am
[11] => 3:45am
[12] => 4:00am
[13] => 1:00pm
[14] => 1:15pm
[15] => 1:30pm
);
```

What i am trying to do is, group them together in sequence and put them into another array separate arrays

So based on the above array, i would get 3 new arrays like so

```
Array
(
[0] => 12:00am
[1] => 12:15am
[2] => 12:30am
[3] => 12:45am
[4] => 1:00am
[5] => 1:15am
[6] => 1:30am
[7] => 1:45am
[8] => 2:00am
);
```

12:00 being the start of the main array and 2:00am is where the pattern stops because the next one is 3:15

```
array
{
[1] => 3:15am
[2] => 3:30am
[3] => 3:45am
[4] => 4:00am
)
```

3:15am being the start of the new pattern in the main array and 4:00am is where the patter stops, and so on..

I have been trying with a loop through the main array and storing the previous time to match up with the current loop + 15 minutes but can't get it work right at all, any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I don't really understand where you're getting 2am or 3:15am from

Comment: What do you mean where am i getting it from?

Comment: maybe you should describe the pattern you are trying to use?
Also, after 12:00am you would normally get 1pm, no?

Comment: How do you decide to split it at 2am and start again at 3:15am

Comment: The pattern is that the time go up by 15 minutes intervals, so when looping through it, if the previous element is not -15 minutes of the current elements then save all previous elements to separate array and carry on with the rest.

Comment: @Shardj because 2am to 3:15am is not a 15 minute interval

Comment: I see, ok I'll write an answer

Comment: @Shardj Thank you

Comment: @user3439600. Do you know in advance that the pattern is 15-minute intervals, or do you need to deduce that from the input array?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Wimanicesir

It is simply logical and enhanced code

```
<?php
$input = Array
(
"12:00am",
"12:15am",
"12:30am",
"12:45am",
"1:00am",
"1:15am",
"1:30am",
"1:45am",
"2:00am",
"3:15am",
"3:30am",
"3:45am",
"4:00am",
"1:00pm",
"1:15pm",
"1:30pm",
);
$periods = [];
foreach($input as $time) {
    $hour = substr($time, 0, strpos($time, ':'));
    $partOfDay= substr($time, strlen($time) - 2);
    $index = ($hour== "12") ? "0" : floor($hour/2.00001);
    $periods[$index.":".$partOfDay][] = $time;
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($periods);
echo "</pre>";
exit();
?>
```

**EDITED**

As per OP's logic, I have simplified the logic, Here is the code.

```
$periods = array();
$index = 0;
$old_value = 0;
foreach($input as $time) {
    //converting time to minutes
    $new_value = (intval(date("H",strtotime($time)))*60) + intval(date("i",strtotime($time)));
    if($new_value > ($old_value+15)){
        $index++;
    }
    $periods[$index][] = $time;
    $old_value = $new_value;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this correct, the OP clarified in comment below my code that the condition of the array who has to be split is the 15 minute interval. If it exceeds this, it should start a new array. In your result it splits 1:00 and 1:15. However upvote for trying and mentioning that you used my code (not a lot of people do that :) )

Comment: It will split your array into 2 hours slot arrays. Ex - 12:00am to 2:00am and 2:01am to 4:00am up to 12:00pm to 2pm. Please don't confuse with the index of the output arrays.

Comment: @Wimanicesir - I agree with your comments and as per your comments, OP has to produce the simple logics with time values and array.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
<?php
$times = [
    '12:00am',
    '12:15am',
    '12:30am',
    '12:45am',
    '1:00am',
    '1:15am',
    '1:30am',
    '1:45am',
    '2:00am',
    '3:15am',
    '3:30am',
    '3:45am',
    '4:00am',
    '1:00pm',
    '1:15pm',
    '1:30pm'
];

$previous = null;
$results = [[]];
foreach ($times as $time) {
    if (
        $previous === null ||
            (new \DateTime())->createFromFormat('h:ia', $time)->getTimestamp() -
            (new \DateTime())->createFromFormat('h:ia', $previous)->getTimestamp() === 15*60
    ) {
        $index = count($results)-1;
    } else {
        $index = count($results);
    }
    $results[$index][] = $time;
    $previous = $time;
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($results);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output (html view):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "12:00am"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "12:15am"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "12:30am"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "12:45am"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "1:00am"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "1:15am"
    [6]=>
    string(6) "1:30am"
    [7]=>
    string(6) "1:45am"
    [8]=>
    string(6) "2:00am"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "3:15am"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "3:30am"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "3:45am"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "4:00am"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "1:00pm"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "1:15pm"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "1:30pm"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an array who splits up the times into hours and am/pm. Is this what you want?

```
<?php
$input =
[ 
"12:00am", "12:15am", "12:30am", "12:45am",
"1:00am", "1:15am", "1:30am", "1:45am",
"2:00am", "3:15am", "3:30am", "3:45am",
"4:00am", "1:00pm", "1:15pm", "1:30pm",
];
// Prepare array
$periods = [];

// Loop all times in input
foreach($input as $time) {
    $hour = substr($time, 0, strpos($time, ':'));
    $partOfDay= substr($time, strlen($time) - 2);
    $periods[$hour][$partOfDay][] = $time;
}
var_dump($periods);
```

Comment: Sorry but no, based on that array i want to loop through it and create 3 new arrays. 1st starting at 12:00am and ending at 2:00am (where the 15 minute pattern stops), 2nd starting at 3:15am (where new pattern starts) and ending at 4:00am (where pattern stops) 3rd starting at 1:00pm (where new pattern starts)

Comment: The pattern is 15 minute intervals

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as a function:

```
<?php

$input = [
    "12:00am",
    "12:15am",
    "12:30am",
    "12:45am",
    "1:00am",
    "1:15am",
    "1:30am",
    "1:45am",
    "2:00am",
    // gap here
    "3:15am",
    "3:30am",
    "3:45am",
    "4:00am",
    // gap here
    "1:00pm",
    "1:15pm",
    "1:30pm",
];
$period = 15;

$result = split_periods($input, $period);

var_dump($result);

function split_periods($times, $period) {
    $standard_diff = $period * 60;
    $separated = [];
    $last_time = null;
    $n = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        $current_time = strtotime($time);
        if ($last_time) {
            $diff = $current_time - $last_time;
            if ($diff != $standard_diff) {
                ++$n;
            }
        }
        $separated[$n][] = $time;
        $last_time = $current_time;
    }

    return $separated;
}
```

Give the function the array of times, and the expected gap between times (in minutes). It returns an array of arrays, as shown below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:00am
            [1] => 12:15am
            [2] => 12:30am
            [3] => 12:45am
            [4] => 1:00am
            [5] => 1:15am
            [6] => 1:30am
            [7] => 1:45am
            [8] => 2:00am
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3:15am
            [1] => 3:30am
            [2] => 3:45am
            [3] => 4:00am
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1:00pm
            [1] => 1:15pm
            [2] => 1:30pm
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used strtotime() to convert time into unix timestamp and count difference with next element.

```
$arr = ['12:00am','12:15am','12:30am','12:45am','1:00am','1:15am','1:30am','1:45am','2:00am','3:15am','3:30am','3:45am','4:00am','1:00pm','1:15pm','1:30pm'];
$new = [];
$temp = [];
$total = count($arr);
for($i=0; $i< $total;$i++){
    $k = $i+1;
    //900 - it is 15 mins difference
    if(isset($arr[$k]) && strtotime($arr[$k]) - strtotime($arr[$i]) == 900){
        $temp[] = $arr[$i];
    }else{
        $temp[] = $arr[$i];
        $new[] = $temp;
        $temp = [];
    }
}
print_r($new);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/B5U1S)